# Prove $\sigma(\{[a,a+1) | a\in\mathbb{R}\})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove that $\sigma(\{[a,a+1) | a\in\mathbb{R}\})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

So I guess I want to prove two inclusions:  $\sigma(\{[a,a+1) | a\in\mathbb{R}\})\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\sigma(\{[a,a+1) | a\in\mathbb{R}\})$

I have previously proven that $\sigma(\{[a,b) | a,b\in\mathbb{R}\})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ which gives the first inclusion since $\sigma(\{[a,a+1) | a\in\mathbb{R}\})\subseteq\sigma(\{[a,b) | a,b\in\mathbb{R}\})$. Now I'm having trouble with the second inclusion, any advice?

Note: $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the borel algebra as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hint: it's possible to obtain $[b,c)$ by finite union and intersection of $[a,a+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $[a,a+1) \cup [a+1,a+2) \cup \ldots = [a, +\infty)$. Hence if $a<b$, then $[a,b) = [a,+ \infty) \cap ([b,+\infty)^c)$. Hence $\sigma (\{[a,a+1) | a \in \mathbb{R}  \}) = \sigma (\{[a,b) | a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$